# why bash executes the file after I compressed it with tar

Tags: bash, tar

When I execute a bash file with the following line,

```
`tar zcvf "${path}${parentFolder}/saveDBHistory_${suffixe}.sql.tar.gz"  -C "${path}${parentFolder}" "saveDBHistory_${suffixe}.sql"`
```

the bash tries to execute the file.
The file is well compressed but the following comment appears in the console:

> saveDBHistory_20220924_1550.sql: command not found

So could you please tell me why the original file is considered as a command?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you think the backticks do? Why did you put them there in your code?

Comment: (I'm serious about looking for an answer to "why did you put them there?" -- been supporting people making this same mistake for almost 20 years now, and nobody has ever answered the question _why_; I don't know if there's some teaching resource or piece of badly-written documentation or something else people are mistakenly following).

Comment: It was exactly the source of the problem! :D

And the reason why the backticks are here is because I work with someone who codes with a very old style. And this file is from him! 
I personally never add them.
Thanks a lot for your quick and efficient help! :)